# How To Get SharePoint Online List Items Attachments Using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

For Attachment Items in any list of  SharePoint Online , graph explorer can get only Attachments property which contains value “true” or “false”.

I am unable to get links of the attached images, pdf, texts etc.

Using Rest API we can easily expand and grab the attached links. However ,Using Graph Explorer we can not expand Attachments property . I Need help that How can we get attachments links  in list of SharePoint online using using Graph API.

The below query I have tried in Graph Explorer: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}

[Attachments: true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juiaC.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not yet supported to retrieve [`ListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) attachment details via Microsoft Graph API.

But you could resort to [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)  for that matter, for example:

```
GET https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{list-title}')/items({item-id})?$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Comment: Any updates on graph api?

Comment: I second...Any updates?

Comment: Any sources for the claim this is not supported?